# ARM Instruction set

Tags: microcontroller, arm, cortex-m0

I am trying to enter into the world of ARM and one thing I come across very often is that ARM processors support ARM and Thumb instruction set.
So it means compiler will use Thumb Instructions which are 16-bit to improve code density and it will use ARM instructions only when absolutely necessary. AM I right?
But now there are newer processors which support Thumb 2 which has 16 bit as well as 32 bit instructions.
But then what makes these newer processors with Thumb 2 superior to the ones which use ARM and THUMB.
I mean basically both the families will have 16 bit as well as 32 bit instructions at their disposal or is there some benefit of having Thumb 2 as compared to having Arm and Thumb instruction sets.
I bought Atmel SAMD21 Kit to develop our new products but before that I am just trying to understand some architecture concepts before I actually start with the hardware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An ARM processor can not execute arbitrary sequences of interleaved ARM and Thumb instructions. It has to be switched from one instruction set to another, e.g. through a branch instruction. So most of the time you tell the compiler to use either ARM *or* Thumb instructions throughout your project. The best the compiler can probably do is to decide on a function-by-function basis which instruction set fits best. The Thumb2 instruction set is supposed to combine the advantages of ARM and Thumb without the drawbacks.

Edit:

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16204494/1015327) to the question @Kynit linked to basically also states the above.

Comment: There are some kinds of code where 32-bit ARM code could outperform the newer alternatives.  The newer alternatives, for example, don't allow one of the registers in a memory operand to be shifted *right*.  Further, some code that makes very heavy use of conditionals could benefit from having the 4-bit conditional field present in every instruction, rather than having to use a special "if/then" instruction.

Answer (score 4):

Thumb2 gives you a few extra instructions that let you take advantage of the ARM feature set in ways that that Thumb couldn't. Thumb2 also supports 16-bit Thumb instructions, so there isn't a huge disadvantage in code size with the new 32-bit instructions. Overall, it looks like you've got the right idea.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15846737/3817091) for more info.